# How to get response body of GET call in RestAPI?

Tags: java, api, get, rest-assured

Am new to API testing. I wanted to validated the response body of the GET method. But it is returning the io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@35adf623 with the below code. Please let me know how can I resolve this. With POST Method, it works fine. Failing with GET method provided am passing all other values correct.

```
    public static Response getResponseWithGetMethod() throws Exception {
    Response response = RequestInvoker.invokeGET();
    return response;
}
```

Output :

```
io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@35adf623
```

Expected output is :

```
 {
"path1": true,
"path2": true,
"path3": true
}
```

Comment: what you've got is an object. Either jsonify the ```response``` or add a ```toString()``` method to your object (provided you wrote that class which seems unlikely)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`body()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/1.4.5/com/jayway/restassured/internal/RestAssuredResponseImpl.html#body()) method to get access to the body of the response.

Answer (score 0):

Response object has multiple fields in it like, body, headers, status code, cookies etc.,
Check out the complete java doc [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/latest/com/jayway/restassured/internal/RestAssuredResponseImpl.html).

Answer to your code is to call `getResponseWithGetMethod().body()` or `getResponseWithGetMethod().asString()`; later one might be appropriate for you.